# Special characters turn into squares

Tags: android, fonts

We've got an issue with our app in Android and would appreciate any help.

**What's the issue?**
Basically if special fonts are used, they will turn into squares on the app. Such as this font:   (taken from: https://lingojam.com/FancyTextGenerator).

This doesn't just happen on the app, but anywhere on the phone, however we'd still like too add solution for it on the app to avoid the squares.

This only affects **Android 5.0, 6.0** (probably lower and 7.0), 8+ is fine, so this obviously means that the special aren't supported in those versions.

**How could this be solved?**
Now when using the Trello app, we noticed that when you make use of this font on there, it is just converted into normal font style. This would be an ideal solution, however we don't know how they did that.

Any ideas how that could be done?

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

- We use it in a textview, yes.
- Asci codes/emojis work, it's only those special fonts (for the mentioned android versions)

Isn't there a general method to detect special fonts and just convert them within  an Android app?

Comment: Without code, we're guessing.  How are you loading the font?  Where are you using the font?  In a text view?  A web view?  Something else?  Do all characters turn into squares?  Just non-ascii?  Just emoji?

Comment: @GabeSechan I've added more info to the post. Ty.

Comment: SHow the code you use to load the font into the textview.  Downlaodable fonts didn't exist until 8.0, so if you're not doing the loading yourself it won't work on pre-8.0 devices

Answer (score 0):

1) you're talking about *text*, not *fonts*. Certain *text* does not render correctly because the *fonts* that are used to render the text don't contain any outlines for (part or all of) that text. Like trying to render Chinese text with an English-only font: it won't work and you'll just get the "not supported" character, which is almost universally a rectangle or diamond. So,

2) the solution is to install proper language support on the device, or for your own app: include a font that supports the text you use.

Comment: Interesting - I have a font which displays this symbol `⦁` correctly on API 34, but as a square in API 24. So there is something else at work besides font.

Comment: API 24 is Android 7 from 2016. Anything that doesn't work in that is kind of irrelevant given that it's dead?

Comment: Tell that to the marketing team :D

Comment: that's your job, not mine =)